# Jenkins - Execute Shell Build Step Not Working

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I'm trying to create a job in Jenkins that will execute a simple shell script.  However, it seems that Jenkins isn't actually doing anything with my script.  No matter what value I put into the **Execute Shell Command** section, Jenkins always says that it passes.  Even if I put in a bogus filename like "RandomBogusFilename.sh" it'll say the job was a success.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong and how I can get Jenkins to actually use my shell script?

The shell script, the job config, and the console output are all shown below.  I'm currently trying to do this on a **Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard** machine.

Thanks.

---

### My .sh file

**File Name:** surveyToolRequest.sh
**File Location:** /jobs/Jeff Shell Script Test/workspace
**Description:**
Hit a web address and retrieve the HTTP Response.  Then print out the HTTP Response.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

response_code=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://SOME-WEBSITE.COM)
echo "The response code is " $response_code
```

---

---

### My Jenkins Job Config

---

[image: Jenkins Job Config]

---

---

### Jenkins Console Output

---

[image]

---

Comment: Just to check: Jenkins is running on a Windows machine, correct? Do you have Cygwin or something installed that bash/curl/etc. can be called directly from the Windows environment?

Comment: Correct.  Jenkins is running on a Windows machine. (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard).

I have cygwin installed.  Now whether or not it is set up properly for bash/curl/etc to call directly, I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: You have to provide the FULL PATH of the script I guess

Comment: It does not have to do with full path. I believe your problem has to do with how Jenkins invokes the shell. You may want to read up on this a little bit more. (Starting source: http://www.porkchopsandpaintchips.com/2013/09/21/taking-control-jenkins-execute-shell/)

Comment: @sputnick I tried that previously and unfortunately, that didn't solve the issue.  That's when I started feeding it bogus file paths to things that don't even exist when I noticed that this was hapening.

Comment: @JasCav Thanks for responding.  I followed the example you provided.  Now I'm getting this error.  Could you possibly offer any additional advice ?

`FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:/cygwin/usr/local/bin/bash-wrapper.sh" (in directory "C:\Users\JW031544\.jenkins\jobs\Jeff Shell Script Test\workspace"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

Comment: Well, after wasting way too much time trying to get this to work, I just decided to go ahead and do what I need with a Batch file.  Maybe I'll revisit this some day in the future.  Thanks to those who offered advice.

Answer (score 3):

I played with this and found that it worked if I specified the path to the script.  If the script is in your job's workspace directory,

```
./surveyToolRequest.sh
```

should work as Jenkins looks for files relative to the root of the workspace.

It's more common to just put the contents of the script file directory into the job configuration; that way you can see what the job is doing and you'll avoid problems like this one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll try it later tonight or first thing in the morning and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Chiefwarpaint and...?

Comment: @PantaRhei I did respond to this thread the next day.  If you show all comments, you can see my last reply.  

Here it is again :: 

Well, after wasting way too much time trying to get this to work, I just decided to go ahead and do what I need with a Batch file. Maybe I'll revisit this some day in the future. Thanks to those who offered advice. –  Chiefwarpaint Dec 12 '14 at 2:54

Answer (score 1):

You should use run "Execute windows batch command" and not "Execute Shell"

Comment: Question creator says he is using cygwin, so Execute Shell should be fine.