# Jenkins not validating the shell command

Tags: jenkins, titanium

I am trying to configure Jenkins for my titanium application. Everytime I am getting the build as SUCCESS, even if I have not entered anything in "Excecute shell" under the build section. I am trying to give the shell commands directly there instead of mentioning that in a seperate bash file.Is there anything to provide in configuration to valide the bash commands?

I have refered the below link which seems like the same issue that I face, but couldnt find a solution.
[Jenkins - Execute Shell Build Step Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412349/jenkins-execute-shell-build-step-not-working)

Comment: It will be more helpful if you share the shell commands which you used:-)

Comment: appc run -p android

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is expected because an empty file is a valid bash script:

```
$ touch empty.sh
$ bash empty.sh
$ echo $?
0
```

If you want the shell build step to fail, try adding a failing command e.g. `exit 1` or `false` in the input field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jil. But,my problem is Jenkins is not validating anything that I enter under Exceute shell section.